# Can I set the return value of a recursive function to a const?

Tags: c++, recursion, constants, return-value

I am writing a binary tree(using linked node representation) in c++.
I want to write a member function to count number of nodes in the tree, so I write a recursive  function to do this job:

```
template<class Item> size_t binary_tree<Item>::count_node(
                                binary_tree_node<Item>* const node)
{
    if(node == NULL) return 0;
    else return 1 + count_node(node->get_left())
                  + count_node(node->get_right());
}
```

I set this function in the private in the binary_tree class. I have a public function size() to call it:

```
template<class Item> size_t binary_tree<Item>::size()
{
    return count_node(root);
}
```

Now here comes my question: if I write size() like the code up, it works fine. But if I set the return value to const like this:

```
template<class Item> size_t binary_tree<Item>::size() const
{
    return count_node(root);
}
```

this code can't compile. Compiler complain that can't transfer size_t to const size_t. How to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Any methods that are called inside of a `const` method need to be `const` themselves. So in your case, the `count_node` class also needs to be marked `const`.

More formally, when you get inside of a function marked `const`, the `this` pointer becomes a `const T*`, and thus you can't call any methods using it that don't also accept a `const T*`, because then you would have to cast a `const T*` to a `T*`, which isn't allowed. If you really want to do something that isn't const, you can use `const_cast` to remove the const-ness (not recommended), or use volatile members/methods.

Comment: @Tian Glad this helped. Also, for future reference, you don't have to @-mention someone if they wrote the post, they will always be notified.